# table with multirow

Tags: tables, errors, pdftex, multirow

I'm a very beginner with LaTeX and I have a problem with `table` and command `\multirow`, I need a small table and I don't know what is wrong in this what I've already wrote. 
I have this error all the time :

```
    (no line number):
    Runaway argument?
    {\textbf {Lata 1960-te} \\ \hline \hline \multirow {3}{*}{\centering \ETC.
    ! File ended while scanning use of \multicolumn.
    <inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> main.tex
```

And here is what I've wrote

```
\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{l|}c||p{2cm}|} \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Lata 1960-te} \\ \hline \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\centering 1961} & \emph{Pamiętnik znaleziony w wannie} \\ \cline{2}
& \emph{Powrót z gwiazd} \\ \cline{2}
& \emph{Solaris} \\ \hline
1968 & \emph{Głos Pana} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

And that's how my table should looks

[image]

Please help me with latex code for the table

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You missed the closing `}` at the end of, i.e. use `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Lata 1960-te}}`; You have closed `\textbf{...}`, but not the 3rd. argument of `\multicolumn`. Apart from this 'easy' to spot error: Please do not post such fragments of code if you have more elaborate questions.

Comment: Also, `\cline{2}` contains a syntax error; it should be `\cline{2-2}`.

Comment: thank You for the answer but even when I write "}" in that place it still doesn't work

Comment: @JuliaOrfin - Have you changed both instances of `\cline{2}` to `\cline{2-2}`?

Comment: Yes now I've changed and it works! Thank You very very much

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as having been answered in the comments.

Comment: @Mico: Ooops, I missed that

Answer (score 0):

There are several syntax errors. Maybe one of these  is what you want? I added a layut with `hhline` which looks better:
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{array,multirow,hhline}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

```
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{l|}c||p{2cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Lata1960-te}}&&\\
\hline\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\centering1961}&\emph{Pamiętnikznalezionywwannie}&&\\\cline{2-4}
&\emph{Powrótzgwiazd}&&\\\cline{2-4}
&\emph{Solaris}&&\\\hline
1968&\emph{GłosPana}&&\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{l|}c||p{2cm}|}
\hhline{---||-}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Lata1960-te}}&&\\
\hhline{===::=}
\multirow{3}{*}{\centering1961}&\emph{Pamiętnikznalezionywwannie}&&\\
\hhline{|~|--||-}
&\emph{Powrótzgwiazd}&&\\
\hhline{|~|--||-}
&\emph{Solaris}&&\\
\hhline{|---||-}
1968&\emph{GłosPana}&&\\
\hhline{---||-}
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\centering` may safely be removed from `\centering 1961`. Also, it looks like the OP wants to create a 2-column, not a four-column, table.

Comment: @Mico: I wondered, but I'm not sure. Maybe she didn't write everything?